# RecyclerView ListAdapter does not update list correctly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, rx-java, android-adapter, android-room

I'm using `Android Room` and `Rx Flowable` to update a `RecyclerView` will the object from my database. For better animation and performance, I updated the project to use the new [ListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/ListAdapter) in my project.

The problem is when user presses a `Checkbox` the Task object is updated as completed, the database reflects this change, but *sometimes* the adapter `ListAdapter` notifies my `onBindViewHolder` and sometimes it says that my view is already updated.

### TaskListFragment

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    viewModel.loadTasks(onTasksLoaded = { adapter.submitList(it) })
}
```

### TaskDao

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM task")
fun getAllTasks(): Flowable<MutableList<Task>>
```

### TaskListAdapter

```
class TaskListAdapter : ListAdapter<Task, BindingHolder<*>>(TaskDiffCallback()) {

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BindingHolder<*>, position: Int) {
        val task = getItem(position)
        // more binding code

        // THE ISSUE IS HERE
        if (task.completed) {
            holder.viewStrike.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            holder.viewStrike.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        }
    }

    // more adapter code
}
```

### Task

```
data class Task(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "task_is_completed") var completed: Boolean = false,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "task_description") var description: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "task_category_id") var categoryId: Long? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "task_due_date") var dueDate: Calendar? = null
) : Parcelable {

    @IgnoredOnParcel
    @ColumnInfo(name = "task_id")
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Long = 0
}
```

### DiffUtil

```
class TaskDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Task>() {

    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Task, newItem: Task) =
        oldItem.id == newItem.id

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Task, newItem: Task) =
        oldItem.task == newItem.task
}
```

Debugging the app, *sometimes* the `isCompleted` field updates correctly and *sometimes* the field is already updated during the Diff, so it says that the view has no updates. I couldn't find any pattern to this issue. In my case, sometimes the view `holder.viewStrike` changes its visibility and sometimes it remains in inconsistent state.

The issue seems related to the `ListAdapter` itself which sometimes sends the `oldItem` with the updated value, so there is no diff to be updated.

Am I missing any implementation?

Comment: Did you every find the solution here?  I might be running into a similar issue.

Comment: @Bink, no I couln't find the solution. I debugged several times, replaced Rx for LiveData, tried different approaches in DiffUtil.ItemCallback with no success.

Comment: I think the error is that `AsyncListDiffer#submitList` evaluates `newList == mList`, and If you just change an item, but not the (size) of the list, this statement is true and the update process is cancelled. But I didn't find a workaround yet.

Answer (score 0):

It might be late, but I will write an answer for others.
You should not use areContentsTheSame in this way.
You have to compare values related this two object which can get changed.
like:

```
 override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Task, newItem: Task){
  return if(oldItem.completed == newItem.completed && oldItem.description == newItem.description && oldItem.dueDate == newItem.dueDate)}
```

But comparing values which can never get changed is not necessary like : id

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your reply. But since I'm using data class, comparing by the way I'm doing, it will return false if any attribute is different. So, I can't see a huge difference between my approach and yours.